# JavaScript scope confusion

Tags: javascript, scope

I have this definition of `TabList`:

```
MyApp.TabList = function (selector) {

    var private = {
        $list: $(selector),
        tabs: []
    };

    this.add = function (tab) {
        private.tabs.push(tab);
    };
};
```

When I call this, however, and break in the body of `this.add`, `private` doesn't appear in the local scope:

```
MyApp.tabs = new MyApp.TabList("#tabs");

$("#tab-add").click(function() {
    MyApp.tabs.add(new MyApp.Tab("title"));
});
```

Does `private` not retain inside the object?

If this code works standalone as above, I might have missed something—I tried to simply it the best I could for demonstrative purposes.

Comment: @Agile Generally you want to end constructor functions with `return this;`. I don't think that it makes a difference, but that's a good practice (from what I've heard).

Comment: @Agile The `private` variable isn't supposed to be in the local scope of the `add` function - it is in its outer scope (the scope of the `TabList` constructor function).

Comment: @Šime Vidas: huh? Why would you do that? Provided you are using `new` there is never any need to do that. You'd only do that if you're making it work without the `new` keyword.

Comment: @Chris I thought I heard that advice, but I'm not so sure anymore. :)

Comment: @AgileMeansDoAsLittleAsPossible I must say, you picked a pretty unfortunate name for comment replies. Do you get a notification on "@Agile"?

Comment: @Šime Vidas: it's based on the first three characters.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the *closure* property, the variable should definitely be available within the add() function.

This might not be the answer, but `private` is a Javascript keyword. You should try avoiding using it as a name for a variable. It can cause unknown bugs to arise, and sometimes debuggers won't help. Give it a shot and let us know if it works!

Comment: Changed "private" to underscore character and problem persists. :(